# ReactJs screen re-rendering

Tags: reactjs, onclick, rendering, onchange

I have an input field and a button to programmatically generate the text for the same field. The OnClick programmatically assign the new value to the this.state.assetsGooglemapslink field, it displays, but gets reset to the original value immediately when the screen re-renders.
Is the Onclick and OnChange are conflicting.

What do I need to adjust?

...

```
createGooglemapslinkHandler= () => {
    this.setState({assetsGooglemapslink: "https://www.google.com/maps/place/" + this.state.assetsLatitude + "," + this.state.assetsLongitude});
}
changeGooglemapslinkHandler= (event) => {
    this.setState({assetsGooglemapslink: event.target.value});
}

                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <label> GoogleMaps Link: </label>
                                        <input placeholder="assetsGooglemapslink"                                                    name="assetsFcclink" 
                                            className="form-control" 
                                            readOnly = {this.state.isReadOnly} 
                                            value={this.state.assetsGooglemapslink} 
                                            onChange={this.changeGooglemapslinkHandler}style={{marginLeft: "10px"}}
                                        />
                                    <div class="input-group-btn">
                                        <button className="btn btn-success" disabled={this.state.isReadOnly} 
                                        onClick={this.createGooglemapslinkHandler}
                                        style={{marginLeft: "10px"}}>Create Link</button>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="input-group-btn">
                                        <button className="btn btn-success" disabled={this.state.isReadOnly} 
                                        onClick={()=> window.open(this.state.assetsGooglemapslink, "_blank")} 
                                        style={{marginLeft: "10px"}}>Google Map</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

...

Comment: try adding e.preventDefault() to your onClick function before doing anything else

Comment: @Shamim Fahad
I added the code to the OnClick createFcclinkHandler and it fixed it like a charm!
Thank you for your suggestion.  I have learned something new !